# Use Named Range in UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a UDF that will use a named range. My named range ("best_Grade") is a single cell, with a value.  (The named range is scoped to the Workbook).

In a workbook module, when I try to create the variable using a named range, I get

> Run-time error '1004': Method of 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Neither line works:

```
Dim namedRng As Range
Dim locDataWS As Worksheet

Set locDataWS = Sheets("Approval matrix 16")
Set namedRng = Range("best_Grade") ' errors
Set namedRng = locDataWS.Range("best_Grade") ' When I take above line out, this line errors too
```

and I've tried:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set namedRng = wb.Names("best_Grade").RefersToRange
```

How come it's erroring out? [This page](http://excel.tips.net/T003106_Using_Named_Ranges_in_a_Macro.html) says it should be working, no?  Do I have to put this UDF on the actual sheet object, and not in a workbook module?

Edit: Note: the named range is not set to a cell, but a SumIf formula (best_Grade = SumIf(A2:A10,"x",...)` which may be causing the error?

Edit2: Yeah, that's why I think. I created a named range for a random cell, and was able to use `Range("a_grade").Value` and it returned the expected value.  Since my `best_Grade` range is a formula, I think that's why it's erroring out.  However, I don't know why, as I'd think a named range is a named range, no matter what it's made up of...

Edit n+1: Note there are two "answers" to this.  If I wanted to continue using a named range  as a `Range` variable, see my answer below.  However, what I really wanted to do was what @MacroMarc posted, so I chose that as the "Answer".

Comment: Looks like The Joker's got you beat. Um, I don't know. Have you tried without using the name, just the cell? Edit: whoever invited me to chat, it's blocked at work :/

Comment: If you query the range in the Immediate Window, do you get a value? (To get to Immediate Window, while in the VBE, press CTRL + G). In the Immediate Window, type something simple like (make sure to lead with the question mark): `? Range("best_Grade").Value`. Does that work or error?

Comment: Is the named range on another sheet that isn't the Active sheet? To test, type the following in the immediate window and press Enter: `?[best_Grade].Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name`

Comment: In my experience, referencing a named range differs from an address in that you must qualify it with the reference to the sheet first. That said, I would have thought the second line you say errors should work as long as the previous line is removed.

Comment: @MacroMan he qualified it though? `Set namedRng = locDataWS.Range("best_Grade")` Edit: oh, are you saying UDF only works on the activesheet?

Comment: @findwindow if that's really what his code looks like, it will error on the first line and never reach the second line where it's qualified.

Comment: @findwindow also, I sent you that invite - I started a [room for VBA](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge)

Comment: @MacroMan - I've included both lines just so you can see what I've tried. When the first line errors, I can skip to the next line (moving the yellow highlighted line), and get the same error on that one.

Comment: @BruceWayne It shouldn't have an impact but have you cleared the error before executing the second line?

Comment: @MacroMan thank you for the invite <3 but chat is blocked at work :/

Comment: @MacroMan - I think I've stumbled on why it's returning such an error. As the named range is not set to a cell, but a formula, it's erroring out. What I guess I'll have to do is just have a helper cell, give *that* a named range, and then use that.  However, if possible, I'd like to use my formula named range...

Comment: @findwindow no worries, no else has took me up on it yet anyway!

Comment: @MacroMan well duh, you smell =P

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, that will be the issue. Have you tried using `Application.Evaluate()` instead?

Comment: Wait, you can set a named range to a formula? What?

Comment: @findwindow - Yep! Check my answer below.

Comment: @BruceWayne yea, just tested it out. Will have to see if I can set it to some index/match formula XD

Comment: @findwindow - a man after my own heart

Comment: @Findwindow I see Scott is no longer your mentor, or you would have tried a defined name for a sumproduct, or aggregate function as well! 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd lol I don't understand sumproduct or aggregate yet XD Scott taught me index/match too but he wasn't commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Names collection instead:

```
Sub t5()
' named range "Test" is `=Sum($A$1:$A$4)`

Dim rng As Double
rng = Evaluate(Names("Test").Value) 
Debug.Print rng
End Sub
```

There are various properties that Name objects have to return string representations.

Comment: you could not have answered like two seconds sooner like just before I started to answer!  Is your ESP broken....no wait, its not and you did it on purpose!  I like your answer better as it gets rid of those extra application and workbook references.

Comment: (I edited and closed that last parenthesis). Thanks for this and your comments!

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub t5()
' named range "Test" is `=Sum($A$1:$A$4)`
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim rng As String

rng = wb.Names("Test").RefersTo
Debug.Print rng

rng = Application.Evaluate(wb.Names("Test").RefersTo)
Debug.Print rng

End Sub
```

After some testing I found the above worked...and kind of interesting.  I got the lead from Macro Man's comment as well at [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefinedNames.aspx) post.

The key is the defined names returns a string ="your result"  so you can either evaluate it to get the answer, or you can do some string manipulation to pull off the quotes and equal sign.  You really were close with your RefersToRange choice.

See Vegard's comment under your own posted answer.

Comment: Yes! That does the trick, thanks for working through it and finding that out.  Cheers! (Now I'm torn if you or @MacroMarc should be flagged as answer!)

Comment: I cannot help you with that decision.  Well maybe I can.  Macro was first, needs more rep points, and I think VBA is more his field than mine.  I am still learning VBA syntax and the dos and don'ts.  They are slightly different answers.  I think his looks cleaner/less verbose for VBA syntax.

Comment: I was thinking the same - gave it to him, but really really appreciate your help! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it wasn't working is because my named range `best_Grades` was not a cell reference, but a formula instead.  Thus, when using `Range("best_Grades").Value`, it was erroring out. (`best_Grades = SumIf(A2:A10,"x", B2:B10, ...)`

Not sure why, since I'd think a named range is a named range, regardless of what makes that up...but I suppose not.

For now, my solution is just to create another named range, based on an actual cell value, and then use that. (`theBest_Grades = A2`).  Then, I can call simply `Range("theBest_Grades").Value` without any issues.

I'll leave this open for a few days, in case someone has an idea of how I can keep my formula named range, and use that in VBA.

Edit: This was basically how I originally had the worksheet/named range:
[image]

with the named range being given as:

[image]

But, as I said, you can't use that type of named range in VBA (at least not that I have found).

So, to solve it, I just used that SumIf in the cell, and gave that cell the named range:

[image]

And now I can use `Range("findWindow_Example").Value` without issue.

Edit n+1:
I tried doing a simple test with a `Double`, same thing though, it errors out:

```
Sub t5()
' named range "Test" is `=Sum($A$1:$A$4)`

Dim rng As Double
rng = Range("Test") 'Run time error 1004
Debug.Print rng
End Sub
```

Comment: I was going to say a named range that covers a range of cells holds cell address values.  ergo your variable which you declared a range can deal with the cell addresses.  When your named range is a formula it returns a result or a value. trying to make your variable which you declared a range equal to a string or some number is a no go.  So if you defined your variable as say a DOUBLE then maybe it will take the value spit out by your named range...and remember to drop the set portion as well me thinks.

Comment: lol dat variable name *^_^* Edit: oh man, you can't do the blush emoji cuz `*` is reserved XD

Comment: @ForwardEd - See my edit, I think I tried what you mentioned. It doesn't work either, unless I misread your comment.

Comment: Take a look at the bottom end of [this explanation](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefinedNames.aspx).  The last three I think.

Comment: @BruceWayne: On the off-chance that this wasn't specified yet -- what ForwardEd is trying to say, is that the named range you specified doesn't return a range object (it returns a string-format formula), which is simultaneously why you can't do `Set rng = Names("test")` and why the answers using `Evaluate` works.

Comment: @vegard Actually with m first comment, I did not realize it returned a string, I just knew it was not returning a range.  Hence why I suggested double...  Your explanation is far superior to my guess work.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I haven't seen mentioned here is that a ground rule for UDF's is broken here IMHO:

ALL information a UDF needs should be passed to the UDF through its arguments.

If you adhere to that rule, using any range name becomes simple, since the value of the range name will automagically be transferred to the argument.

Comment: Thanks for this comment - I've only really used UDF so far for quick tests/checks. I'll for sure keep this in mind as I make them more robust/do other things.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve the problem has been found by more than one answerer, but as I said in the comments (and subsequently, thought might be of interest to others), the reason for the error wasn't specified yet.

The named range you defined does not return a range object. This means that this code:

```
Dim namedRng As Range
Set namedRng = Range("best_Grade")
```

couldn't possibly work (primarily because the named range returns a numerical value. If it returned a string address representation, it might have worked with some syntax improvements).

To illustrate this from the compiler's point of view, look at the print-outs in the immediate window here (the first line in particular):

[image]

If we assume the initial code to be pseudo-code, what was being asked of the compiler was to construct a range out of the formula (not its' result either!).

So if we swap `Set namedRng = Range("best_Grade")` for `Set namedRng = Range(Names("namedRange"))` the result might presumably (but not necessarily -- see end of post!) look like:

```
Set rng = Range("=SUMIF('Ark1'!$B$1:$B$5, "x", 'Ark1'!$A$1:$A$5)")
```

And of course, this would not work. But throwing `namedRange` into an `Evaluate` would, as the other answers demonstrate, be perfectly legal!

---

Interestingly, if we do `? Evaluate(Names("namedRange"))` (omitting the .Value), we get an Error 2015, despite being able to ask the compiler `? Names("namedRange")` and get a string in return!